# Merge in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, merge

I am executing the following merge statement in SQL Server 2008

```
MERGE Nuevo_Nav AS a
USING Tabla_correcta AS b
ON a.[No_] = b.[No_ Documento]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET a.[Respuesta CAE_CAEC] = b.[Respuesta CAE_CAEC];
```

I have the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'as'.

Comment: I don't see any mistakes here, also not sure why you need `Merge` here.

Comment: because i have 2 tables in my database, but in the table 1 i only have serial number of  bills and in the table 2  i have all data so i think use merge to update 550 bills

Comment: IF that's all you're doing, then why don't you just use a simpler `update`?

Comment: Regarding your actual error what is the compatibility level of the database set to?

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but are you running this in a multi-statement batch/sproc, etc?  If so, make sure there is a semi-colon before the beginning of the merge statement.  That's a new requirement when the merge statement was introduced in SQL 2008.  So:

```
;MERGE INTO Blah
USING Blah2...
SET Blah.a = Blah2.b;
```

or

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000) = 'This is my previous code line';

MERGE INTO Blah
USING Blah2...
SET Blah.a = Blah2.b;
```

I forget this every once in a while, since semi-colons after every statement aren't mandatory in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Like Fireblade said, you don't need a `MERGE` here.  This is a simple `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.[Respuesta CAE_CAEC] = b.[Respuesta CAE_CAEC]
FROM Nuevo_Nav a
INNER JOIN Tabla_correcta b
  ON a.[No_] = b.[No_ Documento]
```